# is there a way to add custom html inside the Popconfirm in antd and React

Tags: reactjs, antd

following this implementation =>

https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001

I would like to create a similar thing, when I click on a button, the popup appear and inside the popup instead of just simple text and buttons, I want a fully custom html. (or a react component)

I couldn't find any way to do it.

I tried to add the

```
  <Popconfirm
    placement="leftBottom"
    title={text}
    onConfirm={confirm}
    okText="Yes"
    cancelText="No"
  >
    <Button>LB</Button>
    if(this.state.isOpen){
       <div>custom<div>
    }
  </Popconfirm>
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Fix your codepen

Comment: the codepen is the third exemple of the doc =>
https://ant.design/components/popconfirm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`title` property](https://ant.design/components/popconfirm/#API) of `Popconfirm` which accepts a `ReactNode`.

Note that [`Tooltip` API](https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#API) is available for this component.

```js
<Popconfirm
  placement="topRight"
  title={<div>custom</div>}
  onConfirm={() => console.log("confirmed")}
  okText="Yes"
  cancelText="No"
>
  <Button>TR</Button>
</Popconfirm>
```

[image: Edit Q-57803203-CustomPopConfirmTitle]